# Windows - DOS era MODE.COM command is still functional

Tags: windows, 16-bit

So, for some reason, on Windows 10, the DOS MODE.COM command is still fully functional. Why? I don't understand why they left this in, considering it would need to be updated from 16 bit to 32 bit, as 16 bit programs do not run on newer NT kernels. Any explanations for this?

Comment: Since Windows NT "DOS" was not DOS, it was a DOS-compatible command line interpreter, in the NT stream `mode.com` would probably never have been a 16-bit executable.

Comment: Do you even know the extend of the command mode.com? It can do much more than just changing the screen size.

Comment: @LPChip meant "extent" (and is right).

Comment: Looked into it, and I know what it does now. Just find it interesting that it's still a .COM file. Suppose it's just part of Windows attempt to keep stuff compatible. Now I know how to manually use COM ports in windows, which is nice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### On Windows 10, the DOS MODE.COM command is still fully functional.

> considering it would need to be updated from 16 bit to 32 bit, as 16 bit programs do not run on newer NT kernels.

It is no longer a 16-bit application on Windows 7+:

```
$ file C:/Windows/System32/mode.com
C:/Windows/System32/mode.com: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64, for MS Windows
```

Notes:

1. > The Portable Executable (PE) format is a file format for executables, object code, DLLs, FON Font files, and others used in 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows operating systems.

   Source [Portable Executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable)
2. The `+` is becuase I'm running a 64-bit version of Windows.